# Query use for search in the view

Tags: xpages

I have a xpages booking application, there is a view for search officer's booking record. Due to search values may contains "(" or ")" or other symbols  so I  would use wild card search in the code. Also I need to ensure the search result returns properly so I created extra fields to connect two fields together (e.g. Fieldname1+++Fieldname2). I put the search code in view (In Properties -> Data -> Search in view results)

Here is the code for the search

```
var qstring= "";
if (
(sessionScope.officerSearch != null && sessionScope.officerSearch != "")||
(sessionScope.startDateSearch != null && sessionScope.startDateSearch != "")|| 
(sessionScope.returnDateSearch != null && sessionScope.returnDateSearch !=""))
{
    qstring = " ( FIELD location+++group contains " + sessionScope.locationSearch +"+++"+ sessionScope.groupSearch  +
    " | FIELD location+++officer contains " + sessionScope.locationSearch +"+++"+ sessionScope.officerSearch +")" + 
    " & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=" + sessionScope.startDateSearch + 
    "& FIELD dateYYYYMM <=" + sessionScope.returnDateSearch;
}
return qstring;
```

When I run the application, I have two problems. If I search only one officer, I get an exception (Notes error: Query is not understandable). If I search more than one officer, I don't get the exception but the result does not return anything. So I use a computed field, paste the search code in there and run  the program again. The computed field shows what I searched.

Due to I put the code in the computed field, I can read the whole query for the search

Problem 1: If I search one officer, although it occurs exception, I can imagine the query is like this

( FIELD location+++group contains "*WEST+++GP AM(OSO)*" | FIELD location+++officer contains "*WEST+++John Freeman*") & FIELD CompYMNUM >=201001& FIELD dateYYYYMM <=201712

If I put this query in Lotus Notes Client, and cick Search button, it returns the result properly

Problem 2: If I search multiple officers, although the result does not return anything, the computed field shows the query like this

( FIELD location+++group contains "*WEST+++GP AM(OSO)*" | FIELD location+++officer contains "*WEST+++John Freeman, Kevin Sims, Sally Johnson, Tom Chan, William Ross*") & FIELD dateYYYYMM >=201001& FIELD dateYYYYMM <=201712

I put this query in Lotus Notes Client, and cick Search button, it returns the result properly too.

I feel so strange that the Lotus Notes Client can return the proper result but the xpages cannot. Also I don't understand why if I search one officer, it causes exception (Query not understandable) and if I search more than one officer, it does not exception and not result return.

I think the reason I get the exception or the review does not the the result is I have "(" and ")" in the search value? However, I used wild card search to bound the search criteria (Or I misunderstand the wild card search?)

Also another reason I think is the field location+++officer. If search multiple officers, the field only recognize one officer e.g. "*WEST+++John Freeman, Kevin Sims, Sally Johnson, Tom Chan, William Ross*"?

Last but not least, maybe there is coding mistake in the code? But there is mistake in the code, I guess Lotus Notes Client will not return the result.

I try to solve the problems, but every time when I run the application, those problems still occurs.

Is my query has mistake?

Grateful if someone let me know my mistakes please? Thank you.

Comment: Have you used whatever debugging tool you use (XPages OpenLog Logger, Debug Toolbar, print statement etc) to output the actual query it's passing, to confirm it's what you're expecting? Also, are you testing in Notes Client on the same NSF you're running - the FT Index is specific to the database and field data types are not set by the design but by the data type in the first document with that field name created. So field data types in the FT index can differ between instances of an NSF.

Comment: Do you really use "+" in the name of the field?

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers, thank you for your advice. I checked the Notes Client is running the same NSF as Xpage. Furthermore, in domino designer, in xpage application, I click Application Properties, in Properties tab, I click Index and I see the Index Information shows all are indexed.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, in the view I create many columns in there are. Each column is bound to a field. (I mean in designer, in view, I make a column, I click the column, I choose Field for Display) In the application, some fields only has 1 field e.g.  field location or field officer. however, officer may has many locations, if I have to find officer(s) in a specific location, I need a field the contains location and officer. So in that case in the form, I created a field location+++officer for that issue, "+++" is used to link location and officer together.

Comment: I am thinking about use for loop to loop through the officer field because if search multiple officers, only one officer name has connection with the location field, for example FIELD location+++officer contains "WEST+++John Freeman, Kevin Sims, Sally Johnson, Tom Chan, William Ross. only officer John Freeman is linked to location WEST, the rest officers are only show the name only.